# how to detect onClick or click event on a view added to kendo window

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have kendo window popup which I open on some event being fired. In that kendo window I have added a view using window.content(new View().el).The View contains several divs one of which has id leftarrow.
Onclick on div #leftArrow I need to do something. But I am not able to detect the onclick event .
I have added on the click event listener in the view and given it a callback function. When I put event listener breakpoint on click , the event is firing but somehow it is not getting listened in the view .Can anybody tell where the problem is??

```js
/*This is the controller file where I have created the kendo window and added view in it*/ 
var window = uiLayer.extWindow({
                elem : $('#popUp'),
                actions:["Close"],
                modal: true,
                animation: false,
                resizable: true,
                close: that.onClose,
                width: "95%",
                height: "95%",
                minHeight : "35%",
                minWidth : "60%",
                position:{
                    top:"1%",
                    left:"1%",
                    height:"100%",
                    width:"100%"

                }
              });
            window.open();
            window.content(new PopUpScrollLayoutView(this).el);
/*This is the view in which I have added various templates which contain the div #leftArrow . I have added click event in the events and given it a callback method. 
*/
  PopUpScrollLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

            initialize : function(options){
                console.log("Initialising EventContentView");
                console.log(options.getAllWidgets());
                var allWidgets = options.getAllWidgets();
                this.render(allWidgets);

            },
            events: {
                "click #leftArrow":"leftArrowClicked"
            },

            tagName: "div",
            className: "scrollContent",
            regions : {
                leftArrow : "#leftArrow",
                mainArea : "#mainArea",
                rightArrow : "#rightArrow",
                footer : "#footer"
            },
            render : function(allWidgets){
               this.$el.append(template());
                this.$el.append(mainAreaTemplate());
                this.$el.append(FooterAreaTemplate());
            },
          leftArrowClicked:function(e){
                console.log("Inside left arrow");
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this purpose:

```
$("#leftArrow").click(leftArrowClicked);
```

Comment: Just after the window.content(new PopUpScrollLayoutView(this).el);, and make sure to take out the leftArrowClicked() function outside, anywhere withing the script body.

Comment: Nope , it is not solving the problem

Comment: try inside the render, after appending all regions.

Comment: would you upload a complete running source code so I can help? a sample one that can demonstrate the case.

Comment: The event is getting fired but it is not getting caught in the current view . The event is getting bubbled  to the outer wrapper div of kendo WIndow component. Can't I add event handler inside the marionette view and handle the event??